# Hibernate MappingException when using Logger

Tags: java, hibernate, slf4j

i have a strange error:
I have an annotated class using Hibernate. All was fine until i started to introduce logging like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "GROUP_TABLE")
public class Group {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Group.class);
```

The error produced is:

> [ERROR] Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine
>   type for: org.slf4j.Logger, at table: container, for columns:
>   [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(logger)]

In my understanding a static field should be fine in this context. So why does hibernate try to create a column "logger"?

My dependencies are log4j 1.2.17, slf4j-api 1.7.7 and slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because your class is annotated as both an `@Entity` and a `@Table`, Hibernate assumes that all fields, regardless of modifiers, map to a database column.

Hibernate doesn't care that your field is `static` or `final` (which are Java constructs), all it cares about is that it can't map the field value to a database column. Mark your logger as `@Transient` and Hibernate will ignore it.

Comment: Grrr. I tried that, but oviously worked on some old revision. Now it works like a charm. Thanks!